# How to use laravel pagination & makeHidden and collection method together

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I have a problem with usage laravel pagination with collection method.

My Code:

```
$items = UserItems::whereHas('item.adviser' , function($query) use($request){
            return $query->where('id', $request->adviser_id);
        })
        ->with(['item.adviser', 'user:id,firstname,lastname'])
        ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(answer) DESC, answer DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

And Collection method:

```
$items = $items->each(function ($item, $key){
            if($item->answer !== null){
                $item->answer = true;
            } else {
                $item->answer = false;
            }
        });
```

But when i use collection method the pagination not show in result.

Result (in postman): [Result in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFAhx.png)

Comment: try $items = $items->transform(function ($item, $key){
    if($item->answer !== null){
        $item->answer = true;
    } else {
        $item->answer = false;
    }
    
    return $item;
});

Comment: Use `tap` or `transform` as @JohnLobo said.

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks, but it's not working and i fix it with using traditional foreach loop!!

Comment: @MohsenNazari As i said above, it's not working and i fix it with using traditional foreach loop!!